# SwiftUI default formatter in Text views?

Tags: swiftui

I was surprised to find that some kind of default number formatter is applied to SwiftUI Text? For example, with this code:

`.navigationBarTitle("\(viewingYear)", displayMode: .inline)`

Where `viewingYear` is the integer 1491, it is shown like this:

[image]

How do I disable this behavior so it's shown as 1491 and not 1,491?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the most SwiftUI-y way is this:

```swift
Text(verbatim: "\(viewingYear)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it as string literal like below

```
.navigationBarTitle(LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral: "\(viewingYear)"), 
     displayMode: .inline)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just found out about `Text(verbatim: "\(viewingYear)")`, after checking the docs for this `LocalizedStringKey(stringLiteral:)` thing. A bit shorter :)

Comment: @KevinRenskers I suggest you make “verbatim:” an answer so we can upvote it.